# How do I permanently change the MSYS2 PATH?

Tags: path, msys2

I want to permanently add `/mingw64/bin` to the MSYS2 PATH.

I have tried:

`export PATH=$PATH:/mingw64/bin`

It works until I exit.

After I restart MSYS2 the path has reset to what it was before.

What do I need to do to add `/mingw64/bin` to the PATH so the change persists after I quit and restart the MSYS2 console?

Comment: Wrong question. It's added to the path automatically if you open the MSYS2 terminal the right way. There are different shortcuts for different `/??/bin` directories, the one you need should be along the lines of `... MinGW 64-bit`.

Comment: Correct. I had only used the icon on my taskbar and had not noticed there are multiple executables. The problem is solved when I double click mingw64 instead.

If you wish to add this to the main-thread answers I will be happy to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't manually add `/??/bin` to the PATH in the MSYS2 terminal.

It happens automatically (along with other changes to environment variables) when you open the terminal for [the environment you want to use](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).

There should be different shortcuts for different environments, the one you're looking for should be named along the lines of `... MinGW 64-bit`.

The shortcuts point to executables in `C:\msys64`, which you can run directly (this one is `mingw64.exe`).

Comment: Yes but if mingw is installed in c:\mingw64, and msys2 sets the root / to be c:\msys64 it won't find the installation of mingw, will it?

Comment: @Erik It sets the root to its installation directory. It will work regardless.